# Import jar in a project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I did this very simple java file:

```
public class LibTest {

    public int mySum(int a, int b){

        return a + b;       
    }   
}
```

Then I exported it as a jar file (using Eclipse wizard).

Then I would like to import this jar in a different Java project and use the method `mySum`.

I imported that jar as a `Referenced Library`, but I don't know how to invoke the method from my code.

How can I do?

Comment: First: did you try using that class from *within the original project*? Using it from an imported library is *the same*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First import the class:

```
import mypackage.LibTest;
```

Then instantiate it and call the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LibTest libTest = new LibTest();
    System.out.println(libTest.mySum(1,1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an import statement in your java class and then use the class. 
Eg: import com.mypackage.MyClass;